# Purchase of large blocks in South Africa

Tags: building, sets, compatibility, replacement-parts

I have thousand's of small-single, two and four blocks but sometimes need to build larger structures and thus, would like to know were in South Africa I can 
purchase these larger blocks without all the smaller blocks

Comment: Welcome! Can you clarify what you mean by "blocks"? That is not standard LEGO terminology - do you mean "bricks" - and if yes, are these of the 1xN stud variety, or of the 2xN stud variety - and which dimension are you looking for (e.g. 2x6, 2x10 etc)?

Answer (score 1):

There are some BrickLink stores that operate in South Africa. You should be able to get from them whatever you need. Here is the list of stores:  http://www.bricklink.com/browseStores.asp?countryID=ZA